# Add prefix to each word of each line if it does not exist in bash

Tags: bash

I have an output CSV file like below and need to add a prefix if mrt WORD does not exist in the CSV file.

```
mrt/abc .1, mrt/def .3, mrt/mlz .4, mrt/gyt .5, abc-d .6, lbr-e .7,
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming*: you want to add "mrt/" to *any field* that is missing that prefix:

With a perl one-liner:

```sh
perl -pe 's{, (?!mrt/)}{, mrt/}g' file.csv
```

---

With bash:

```sh
IFS=","
while read -ra fields; do
    fields=("${fields[@]/# /}")
    for ((i=0; i<${#fields[@]}; i++)); do
        [[ ${fields[i]} == mrt/* ]] || fields[i]="mrt/${fields[i]}"
    done
    echo "${fields[*]}"
done < file.csv
```

outputs

```
mrt/abc .1,mrt/def .3,mrt/mlz .4,mrt/gyt .5,mrt/abc-d .6,mrt/lbr-e .7
```